# DTLS handshake problems with ocserv

Tags: ssl, vpn, dtls, openconnect

I have a problem with the configuration of ocserv on CentOS 8. When I try to connect, a DTLS handshake problem occurs on the client side:

```
16:50:51 LIB: DTLS handshake timed out
16:50:51 LIB: DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
```

I tried to re-configure according to some guides, but no results. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you try to capture the traffic for the dtls handshake? Maybe you don't even get any reply. If the handshake timesout later after some exchanged messages, that, in my experience, indicates either credential or implementation issues.

Comment: Sorry, but how i can do it? But i tried to check it from different countries, and different servers.

Comment: Are you common to tools as wireshark? You may have a look at https://github.com/eclipse/californium/wiki/IP-Capturing-%E2%80%90-How-To-Provide-The-Right-Information to see, how to capture the traffic.

Comment: Hi. I found solution. This is bug of OpenConnect android client. At the pc, and anyconnect cisco client all are ok. Thanks for your help.